# Debugging with pdb files not generated at the same time as the Binary. Is it possible?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, windbg, pdb-files

I tend to think it is not possible.
I know that the generated binaries and its counter-part pdb files are tied at compile-time.

Today I have to try to help debugging dumps of a really old version of the product, about which obviously the pbd has been generated at another date.

Visual Studio faithfully tells me that the pbd do not correspond to my binary. (And I always thank it gratefully for that for all the hours it saved me when I was not on the good binary).

---

However, this time the problem is not the same: I do want to use the compilation-time-unrelated pdb files.

I *think* I remember that I read sometime that it is however possible to exploit such pdb, if the source code was the same: I think it involves parsing the pdb, or correcting some timestamp value data inside the pdb itself or something like that... whatever. I may really be wrong on that.

So, even if it's hard, is there a way to use such pdb files that were not generated at the same time as the binary, but with the same exact code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply rebuilding the PDB from the same source may not produce exact results. Consider that the environment was updated meanwhile. You probably use a newer version of the compiler etc.

That said, there is

```
.symopt+ 0x40
```

for WinDbg as mentioned by @blabb already.

If you prefer debugging in Visual Studio, there is this tool that modifies the timestamp: [Chkmatch](http://www.debuginfo.com/tools/chkmatch.html).

```
chkmatch -m <exe> <pdb>
```

which copies the information from the executable to the PDB. This is a bit dangerous: if you forget that this is a modified PDB, you may later hunt bugs that are not present. I recommend

- keeping the original, mismatched PDB
- creating a batch file for copying the PDB and modifying it
- deleting the modified PDB every day

Calling the batch file will remind you that you might get inexact results during your debug session.

Answer (score 4):

.symopt+ 0x40 (load mismatched pdb )